# Photoshop and mac not printing correct size?

Tags: photoshop, printing, rescaling, epson, macbook

Probably a silly question but any help appreciated. 
Trying to print from photoshop CC on MacBook to Epson 9600. Images printing smaller than expected. For example, I've just tried to print a 6x8" image and its printing at about 6x7 3/4". Image size and canvas size both set to 6x8. All tick boxes have no scaling selected and in preview it says 100% and says it will print at 6x8. Paper and page size set custom at 8x8"... But it just won't print correct size.. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you crop the digital image to have a 3:4 aspect ratio?

Comment: What application are you using to print?

Comment: Is there an option for borderless printing? In the preview image, do you see the white stripes along the sides of the paper?

Comment: To answer your questions it might be best to explain what I've done. I've opened an original JPEG in photoshop CC. Adjusted colour etc. opened new image set sizing 6x8", 240dpi. Dragged other image into new canvas and adjusted to fit what I wanted on 6x8" and flattened image. (So it cropped the edges I didn't want) then gone to print, checked all boxes etc to say don't scale down or re sample image. In the print preview there is no boarder. You can actually see it's missing edges somewhere between photoshop and print preview. Set new paper size to 8x8" so have boarders top and bottom

Comment: have you gone to the printer vendor's website to see if there is an up to date driver?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your help all.. After hours of mind boggling research I come to the conclusion it could be software.. Corrupted files... Upgraded computer software, uninstalled and re installed photoshop and bingo... Printing to size

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your help all.. After hours of mind boggling research I come to the conclusion it could be software.. Corrupted files... Upgraded computer software, uninstalled and re installed photoshop and bingo... Printing to size

Comment: Glad you found an answer. Click the √ icon to the left to mark this as the accepted answer -- that'll remove this question from the "unanswered" category and make it easier for people to find questions that still need work. Thanks.